# BS4 cannot select correct 'span'

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have tried to scrape a price from a certain website, a small sample of the HTML code is below:

```html
</div>
</div>
<div class="right custom">
<div class="description custom">
<aside>
<h4>Availability:</h4>
<div>
<span class="label green">In Stock</span>
</div>
</aside>
<aside>
<h4>Price:</h4>
<div>
<span class="label">£65.40</span>
</div>
</aside>
<aside>
<h4>Ex Tax:</h4>
<div>
<span class="label">£54.50</span>
</div>
</aside>
<div class="price">
                    £65.40                  </div>
<section class="custom-order">
<div class="options">
<div class="option" id="option-276">
<span class="required">*</span>
<label>Type &amp; Extras:</label><br/>
<select name="option[276]">
<option value=""> --- Please Select --- </option>
<option value="146">Each                                </option>
</select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="quantity custom">
<label>Quantity:</label><br/>
<input name="quantity" size="2" type="text" value="1"/>
</div>
</section>
<!-- -->
<div class="cart">
<div>
```

I am trying to select the price of £54.50 (which is the price without UK tax).

The code I have used is below:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

var1 = requests.get("https://www.website.co.uk",
headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})
var2 = var1.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(var2, "html.parser")
span = soup.find("span", {"class":"label"})
price = span.text
price
```

Output: 'In Stock'

This 'In Stock' is located a few lines earlier in the HTML code.

```html
<div>
<span class="label green">In Stock</span>
```

Can somebody please point me in the direction of picking up the correct span?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You selected `span = soup.find("span", {"class":"label"})`, the first span with class label and you got it. You get the expected value with `span = soup.find_all("span", {"class":"label"}, limit=3)[2]`

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas, this was most useful. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CSS Selector `nth-child()`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

txt = """THE ABOVE HTML"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, "html.parser")

print(soup.select_one("aside:nth-child(3) > div > span").text)
```

Output:

```
£54.50
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy.spider import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''your html
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)  # create doc
span = doc.getElement('span', start="Price:")
print (span.text)
```

Result:

```
£65.40
```